# install ros-hydro-pr2-desktop on ubuntu 14.04 with indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to install ros-hydro-pr2-desktop or ros-groovy-pr2-desktop on ubuntu 14.04 with ros Indigo? Should I install from source? And if I can install it, can it work correctly on ros indigo? Andy advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195921/install--ros-hydro-pr2-desktop-on-ubuntu-14.04-with-indigo/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Hydro and Groovy are not supported on 14.04 See http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

Most PR2 packages are not yet available in indigo, but a lot of their dependencies are available.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-10-25**:
Thanks,tfoote. You said "Most PR2 packages are not yet available in indigo, but a lot of their dependencies are available." ;what do you mean by "not yet available"? Do you mean that PR2 packages will be available in indigo in the near future so that I don't have to install ubuntu precise instead?

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-10-25**:
Tfoote, is it possible for me to still install PR2 packages and run them (especially the simulator) in indigo now given that their dependencies are available? Can you give me some instructions?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-26**:
Different projects port forward to new distros at different paces. Larger projects take longer. The PR2 is a larger project and there's still work going on to get everything working on hydro. I do expect it to get indigo support, but not soon.

**Comment by [Maestre](https://answers.ros.org/users/13871/maestre/) on 2014-11-25**:
Guys, any news about the port of PR2 to Indigo?